# AS linked library items with TextFields does not works

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I try to use graphics resources(MovieClips, etc) from another SWF.
I have a *.fla file, which has AS3 linked movie clip "GameInterface". Then I publish it as res.swf.

And in my AS3 project I'm using this code to add this MovieClip:

```
public function Main() {
    var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var myUrlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("res.swf");
    myLoader.load(myUrlReq);
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
}

private function onLoaded(e: Event): void{
    var test:Class = e.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("GameInterface") as Class;
    var testMC:MovieClip = new test() as MovieClip;
    addChild(testMC);
}
```

And it works fine, if there is no any TextFields in my GameInterface movie clip.
But if I have a TextField in GameInterface, it raises error:

```
[Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable GameInterface is not defined.
```

So what am I doing wrong? How can I import MovieClips with TextFields, to use it in my project?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I used TLF Text instead Classic Text. With Classic Text it works fine.